# Schedule to start an EC2 instance and run a python script within it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to schedule my python script in AWS, however I don't want the instances to be running all the time. So, trying to automate the process of:

1. Start the EC2 instance on a specific time
2. Run the python script within it
3. Stop the EC2 instance once the job is completed.

I cannot run this script directly as a Lambda function because the script does some parallel processing which requires more RAM, so choosing a bigger AWS instance rather than writing it as a lambda function. Also, don't want this instance to be running all the time as it is expensive.

So far, I followed [Automatic starting and stopping of AWS EC2 instances with Lambda and CloudWatch · matoski.com](https://matoski.com/article/aws-automatic-start-stop-instances-lambda/) and created a Lambda function to start and stop the instance at specific time, however I couldn't find a way to run the python script once the instance is started.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Call the script from `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: But how do I stop the instance once the script completes.

Comment: You write your script to invoke the OS shut down command

Comment: Oh that’s new. Can we do that instance shut down from within the script? Any example please. Otherwise no problem, I will try to find it. But thanks for the input.

Comment: It'll require root permissions, but see various solutions here (not sure about the accepted answer myself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013274/shutting-down-computer-linux-using-python

Comment: You say "I cannot run this script directly as a Lambda function because the script does some parallel processing which requires more RAM", but Lambda functions can be allocated a lot of RAM (which also increases the assigned Compute resources).

Comment: You can also attach an IAM role to the EC2 instance with `ec2:StopInstances` permissions. Steps: Start instances using CloudWatch events, Run your scripts. Once script execution is done, get the instance id from the meta-data (`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`) and issue `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-XXXX`

Comment: @cricket_007 everything works, except the shutdown. I was using os.system("sudo shutdown now -h")  at the end of my python script, my ssh connection dropped, but when I looked at the instance in aws UI, it is still running.

Comment: That terminates the ec2- instance. Please no one use the shutdown command there. I lost some of my data now. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MY application runs an instance @ 13:39 UST everyday and self shuts down after processing is complete. It uses below

1. A scheduled lambda function using cloud watch event rule

[Cloud watch Event/rules config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhq6L.png)

2. The lambda trigger will start an instance (with hardcoded id)

```html
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-south-1')
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxx'])
    print('started your instances: ' + str('i-xxxxxx'))
    return
```

3. This triggers an instance which has a cron running to execute Python script

   @reboot python /home/Init.py
4. Once script completes, python job shuts down itself using below snippet

```html
import boto.ec2
import boto.utils
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger()
def stop_ec2():
    conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("ap-south-1") # or your region
    # Get the current instance's id
    my_id = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['instance-id']
    logger.info(' stopping EC2 :'+str(my_id))
    conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])
```

Comment: How do you make cron job to run once the instance starts?

Comment: @reboot is the special specification for cron, instead of time/date fields. This ensures script is run when the instance starts/reboots.
I have had success with above configuration using Amazon Linux AMIs

Comment: Thanks. But where do you specify that @reboot command. Is that a shell script? Can you explain that a bit?

Comment: I'd launched an instance, copied py scripts &
Added below
sudo crontab -e
 @reboot /usr/bin/python /path/to/file/script.py

Then stopped the instance. This the same instance which is being started by lambda using instance id

Comment: I fired an instance , added @reboot in Cron using 
Sudo crontab -e
Copied all scripts, and then stopped the instance. 
Later lambda will fire start for the same instance using instance id and the script runs cause of @ reboot

Answer (score 4):

For future developers, who come to this question, a newer approach to this is:

1. Create your EC2 with a role containing `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM` policy
2. Create a lambda to do the wake-up, run command, shutdown
3. Use a Cloudwatch Event to trigger the lambda

So:

1. Follow the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html
2. Use the following lambda skeleton:

```
import time
import boto3

REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'

WORKING_DIRECTORY = '<YOUR WORKING DIRECTORY, IF ANY>'

COMMAND = """
    echo "Hello, world!"
    """

INSTANCE_ID = '<YOUR INSTANCE ID>'


def start_ec2():
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID])

    while True:
        response = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID], IncludeAllInstances=True)
        state = response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']

        print(f"Status: {state['Code']} - {state['Name']}")

        # If status is 16 ('running'), then proceed, else, wait 5 seconds and try again
        if state['Code'] == 16:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(5)

    print('EC2 started')


def stop_ec2():
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID])

    while True:
        response = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID], IncludeAllInstances=True)
        state = response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']

        print(f"Status: {state['Code']} - {state['Name']}")

        # If status is 80 ('stopped'), then proceed, else wait 5 seconds and try again
        if state['Code'] == 80:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(5)

    print('Instance stopped')


def run_command():
    client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=REGION_NAME)

    time.sleep(10)  # I had to wait 10 seconds to "send_command" find my instance 

    cmd_response = client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID],
        DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
        DocumentVersion="1",
        TimeoutSeconds=300,
        MaxConcurrency="1",
        CloudWatchOutputConfig={'CloudWatchOutputEnabled': True},
        Parameters={
            'commands': [COMMAND],
            'executionTimeout': ["300"],
            'workingDirectory': [WORKING_DIRECTORY],
        },
    )

    command_id = cmd_response['Command']['CommandId']
    time.sleep(1)  # Again, I had to wait 1s to get_command_invocation recognises my command_id

    retcode = -1
    while True:
        output = client.get_command_invocation(
            CommandId=command_id,
            InstanceId=INSTANCE_ID,
        )

        # If the ResponseCode is -1, the command is still running, so wait 5 seconds and try again
        retcode = output['ResponseCode']
        if retcode != -1:
            print('Status: ', output['Status'])
            print('StdOut: ', output['StandardOutputContent'])
            print('StdErr: ', output['StandardErrorContent'])
            break

        print('Status: ', retcode)
        time.sleep(5)

    print('Command finished successfully') # Actually, 0 means success, anything else means a fail, but it didn't matter to me
    return retcode


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    retcode = -1
    try:
        start_ec2()
        retcode = run_command()
    finally:  # Independently of what happens, try to shutdown the EC2
        stop_ec2()

    return retcode
```

3. Follow the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Comment: Isn't there a Lambda max runtime of 15 minutes? Even if the EC2 launched has higher specs, if it runs longer than 15min then this lambda will simply force quit and the EC2 will never shutdown right?

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems starting and stopping the instance using the solutions in this post. Then I followed the instructions on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/ and it was really easy. Basically:

1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/home and on the left side, click Policies and click Create Policy. Then click on the JSON tab. Then copy paste this to create a new policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/home and on the left choose Roles. Make sure you choose Lambda as your AWS Service, and attach the policy you created in Step 1.
3. Then go to the Lambda console, click Create Function. Choose Python 3.7 and then click the dropdown next to Permissions and Use An Existing Role and attach the IAM role you created in Step 2.
4. Use this as your code:

```
import boto3
region = 'us-west-1' # Dont use the specific, like instead of us-east-1d just write us-east-1
instances = ['i-xxxxxxxxxxxx']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

5. Start your EC2 instance, and type `which python` to find your path to python and write this down. Then, type in `crontab -e` to edit your CRON jobs. Don't use `sudo`...because sometimes `sudo` messes things up when you haven't been using it to run the Python files. In my instance, I had a `pgpass` file storing my password that `sudo` couldn't see , but removing sudo worked!
6. Within the crontab editor after the commented lines, type in `@reboot /path/to/python /path/to/file.py` For example, for me this was `@reboot /home/init/python /home/init/Notebooks/mypredictor.py`
7. At the end of your Python file, you need to stop your instance. You can do it like this:

```
import boto3
region = 'us-west-1' # Dont use the specific, like instead of us-east-1d just write us-east-1
instances = ['i-xxxxxxxxxxxx']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Comment: How do you turn your instance on to modify it after you have done this?

Comment: @Eric sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: you set up the instance to shut itself off after it reboots. So what if you need to turn it on to do some maintenance? As soon as you turn it on, it starts a script to shut itself off.

Comment: @Eric I see what you're saying. Yea, that is problematic! I think you would need to delete the `ec2.stop_instances` line from your Python script (or edit your `crontab`), save and wait for the machine to restart, then you can start up the machine again. Possibly an improvement to this would be: before you call your python script, you run `git pull` to pull any code changes, then you run your python script.