# @reboot ending instance upon attempting to ssh in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, reboot

I have an EC2 instance that uses `@reboot` to run a python script every time the instance starts up. The python script uses `conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])` to stop the instance after the script has finished (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622575/schedule-to-start-an-ec2-instance-and-run-a-python-script-within-it)). Unfortunately, I can no longer ssh into my instance because the python script stops the instance immediately. Is there anything I can do to reset the instance or change the settings manually?

If not, is there any way to grab files from an instance without having to ssh in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shell script that deletes your reboot script.

```
#! /bin/bash
rm -f /path/to/my/python_script.py
```

Add this script as `User Data` to your EC2 instance.

Reboot the instance. The script will run deleting your python reboot script.

Notice the `-f` flag. This means `force`, which will handle files set to read-only.

Go back and remove this script from User Data once you can control / access your instance.

[Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: Hi, @John Hanley I tried this but I'm not sure if the script ever runs because the instance immediately goes from 'pending' to 'stopping'. Maybe `@reboot` has priority over `User Data` scripts?

Comment: More details on how you configured and how you are running your `@reboot` script. I have written other SO answers on how to detach the boot volume, modify it and then reattach as another alternative.

Comment: the command I ran was `@reboot python script_name.py`. The script contains `conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])` which then shuts the instance down before I can ever delete the file. Is there a way to changing the reboot settings without starting the instance?

Comment: From your comment I do not understand how you configured your script to run or what your script contains. Do not leave out details. It is often the little items that point to the real problem / solution.