# Closing window manager & powering off from C#/Mono program

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspbian, openbox

I'm developing a program in mono/C# which will run on a Linux embedded platform with a touch-screen.

I've installed OpenBox in top of Raspbian, because this will run in "kiosk mode" and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

I was planning to have two options in the program:

1. option to shutdown the computer
2. option to close the windows manager (openbox) and return to the terminal

For the first option I've tried using:

```
shutdown
poweroff
systcl poweroff
```

commands but all require special privileges, so I'm not sure on what would be the best approach. Should I create a bash script with root privileges and run this script from the program?

For the second option, I don't even know how to start. I've configured openbox to be able to close it from the keyboard through Ctrl + Alt + Backspace, but I know how to close it from the program.
I've tried using SendKeys with that key combination but does not work.

I've also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013274/shutting-down-computer-linux-using-python) using [DBUS for C#](https://github.com/mono/dbus-sharp) but I've issues compiling it.

Could you please give any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your sudo program up to let a user run a program without any password.
Add to your visudo file:

```
<username-or-ALL> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/poweroff
```

[See this maybe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

If I were you, I would reboot after setting up and before testing.

Comment: Thanks, I think is a great idea.
Regarding the other question, do you have any idea on how openbox could be closed and return to terminal?

Comment: No sorry but I never used openbox