# How to fix "shutdown: NOT super-user" when using a shutdown script in Python?

Tags: python, windows, shutdown

I got this script

```
import os

shutdown = input("Do you wish to shutdown your computer ? (yes / no): ")
if shutdown == 'no':
  exit()
else:
  os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

and when I run it and enter yes it says "shutdown: NOT super-user"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shutting down computer (linux) using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013274/shutting-down-computer-linux-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
  os.system("sudo shutdown /s /t 1")
```

Enter sudo